# tr command: strange behavior with | and \

Tags: bash, escaping, pipe, translate, tr

Let's say I have a file test.txt with contents:

```
+-foo.bar:2.4
|    bar.foo:1.1:test
\|  hello.goobye:3.3.3
   \|+- baz.yeah:4
```

I want to use the tr command to delete all instances of the following set of characters:

`{' ', '+', '-', '|', '\'}`

Done some pretty extensive research on this but found no clear/concise answers.
This is the command that works:

input:

`cat test.txt | tr -d "[:blank:]|\\\+-"`

output:

```
foo.bar:2.4
bar.foo:1.1:test
hello.goobye:3.3.3
baz.yeah:4
```

I experimented with many combinations of that set and I found out that the '-' was being treated as a range indicator (like... [a-z]) and therefore must be put at the end. But I have two main questions:

1) Why must the backslash be double escaped in order to be included in the set?

2) Why does putting the '|' at the end of the set string cause the tr program to delete everything in the file except for trailing new line characters?

Comment: As for (2), could you please show the exact string you were using that had that effect, and specify your current locale's character collation order (which determines how ranges with `-` in them are interpreted)? The output of the `LC_COLLATE=` line emitted by the `locale` command will do.

Comment: BTW, is this interpreting Ivy or Maven output? Since either of those tools can dump dependency resolution results in XML, I would generally use XML-aware tools (XMLStarlet, xsltproc, etc) to interpret them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
tr -d '\-|\\+[:blank:] ' < file
```

You have to escape the `-` because it is used for denoting ranges of characters like:

```
tr -d '1-5'
```

and must therefore being escaped if you mean a literal hyphen. You can also put it at the end. (learned that, thanks! :) )

Furthermore the `\` must be escaped when you mean a literal `\` because it has a special meaning needed for escape sequences.

The remaining characters must not being escaped.

---

Why must the `\` being doubly escaped in your example?

It's because you are using a `""` (double quoted) string to quote the char set. A double quoted string will be interpreted by the shell, a `\\` in a double quoted string means a literal `\`. Try:

```
echo "\+"
echo "\\+"
echo "\\\+"
```

To avoid to doubly escape the `\` you can just use single quotes as in my example above.

---

Why does putting the '|' at the end of the set string cause the tr program to delete everything in the file except for trailing new line characters?

Following [CharlesDuffy's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50221973/tr-command-strange-behavior-with-and/50222043?noredirect=1#comment87462082_50222043) having the `|` at the end means also that you had the unescaped `-` not at the end, which means it was describing a range of characters where the actual range depends on the position you had it in the set.

Comment: Might also be worthwhile to note the distinction between single- and double quotes for purposes of backslashes' interpretation. (Comparing `echo "\\"` and `echo '\\'` is an easy way to get there).

Comment: POSIX (and GNU) `tr` doesn't require `[[:blank:]]`, `[:blank:]` is enough (and your command will actually remove `[` and `]`). Also, `-` as the first or last character in the group doesn't have to be escaped.

Comment: You have to use `-d --`, though, if you use an unescaped `-` as the first character.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I think it is definitely a good idea to *read* the question before going to answer it. :) I'm sorry for that.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Oh yes, it must be `[:blank:]`. Thanks!

Comment: Re: `|`-at-the-end, by definition that means the dash was somewhere else. Where that dash *was*, and thus which character range was between the thing on its left and the thing on its right in their current locale's collation order, is thus very pertinent to reproducing the described behavior.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Ah, yes. Good catch!

Comment: I'm slightly embarrassed that I didn't realize the answer to question number two while simultaneously realizing that `-` defined ranges. Thank you so much for this answer it was very in depth.

Comment: You are welcome. :) Also thanks to Charles and Benjamin for their help!

Answer (score 2):

another approach is to define the allowed chars

```
$ tr -cd '[:alnum:]:.\n' <file

foo.bar:2.4
bar.foo:1.1:test
hello.goobye:3.3.3
baz.yeah:4
```

or, perhaps delete all the prefix non-word chars

```
$ sed -E 's/\W+//' file
```

Comment: Do you want the leading and tailing `[` and `]`? The argument is implicitly a character class already, after all; see [BenjaminW's comment on hek2mgl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50221973/tr-command-strange-behavior-with-and#comment87461699_50222043).

Comment: Oops, tnx. fixed.